# Converting the required time to UTC

Tags: java, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

I have a string time in such format: `14:30`, and need convert it to UTC to correctly make selections from the database. Here is a code to get current time in UTC:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-DD hh:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

1. How to convert `14:50` to UTC (not current time), if it relates to the UTC+6 timezone?
2. I'm using SQLite and `time('now')` in a database query. Will the time returned by this function is well compared with the time that we got in the first point?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This could help you http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/java-timezone-correctionconversion-with-daylight-savings-time-settings/

Comment: `time()` returns times in `hh:mm:ss` format.